# How to create a globally available interface/type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am creating an component library with Preact and TypeScript. I have an icon component which can be used like:

```
<SVGIcon name='camera' width={16} height={24} />
```

And, it is implemented as:

```
export interface SVGIconProps {
  class?: string;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
  name: string;
};

export function SVGIcon(props: SVGIconProps) { /* return svg; */ }
```

In to provide better intellisense for library users, I want to narrow the type of `name` prop to a limited set of string literals (basically show only allowed names for icons). I can, of course, use string literals that library is providing; however, the user is also allowed to dynamically register his own additional icon sets using a register function like:

```
registerIcon('icon-name', jsxFunctionReturningSVGFragment);
```

The `registerIcon` function add the icon and its JSX function to an internal cache (instance of ES `Map`).

That question is how can I retain the narrow typing and provide auto-complete/intellisense for library users considering the fact that they can add one or more icons when consuming the library?

Is it possible to declare a dummy interface/type say `MyLibIconSet` at a library level which the user of the library should then override in his code-base before using the library? Something similar to how we do for declaration merging or using Global augmentation for patching missing types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be achieved with [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).

You could define an interface that has a member for each possible icon. The type would be whatever you like in this case:

```js
export interface SVGPossibleIcons {
  thumbsUp: string;
  thumbsDown: string;
  roflSmiley: string;
}
```

Then you could define your props like this:

```js
export interface SVGIconProps {
  class?: string;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
  name: keyof SVGPossibleIcons;
}
```

The user of the library then has to extend that interface with his/her own icons like this:

```js
declare module "YourSVGModuleName" {
    export interface SVGPossibleIcons {
        anotherCustomSmiley: string;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is clever solution. Thanks.